# How can i enter only one data per Item in Grid

Tags: jquery

Here i have small requirement like  in my dropdown  i have Piza,Burger option When i select any one only once should be enter in Grid not more than one

```
 <select id="Drp_Bake">
    <option value="1">Pizza</option>
    <option value="2">Burger</option>

</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="Bake_Items" />

<div id="DisplayItems"></div>
```

**JqueryCode**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var key = [];
$('#Bake_Items').click(function () {
    var Menus= $('#Drp_Bake').val();
    var Bake_Items= key.push(Menus);
 $('#DisplayItems').append(Bake_Items);
})
```

The Items Stored in Key Array but its should be Inserted only not more-than once

Comment: What is the "Grid"?  Do you want to change the content of the grid when you swap your selection?  Are other dropdowns feeding this grid too?

Comment: Yes Bro wen i select Pizza & click on Enter Pizza Display in Div again if i select Pizza its shows me u had already selected ...please Selected another1

Comment: You can use `$('#DisplayItems').text(Bake_Code)` and that will replace the text in the display div each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Code**

```
<select id="Drp_Bake">
  <option Value="0">-Select-</option>
  <option value="1">Pizza</option>
  <option value="2">Burger</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="Bake_Items" />

<div id="DisplayItems"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var key = [];
            var selected;
            $('#Bake_Items').click(function () {
                selected = $('#Drp_Bake option:selected').text();

                if (selected == '-Select-') {
                    alert('Please Select any Value...');
                }
                else if (jQuery.inArray(selected, key) == -1) {
                    key.push(selected);
                    $('#DisplayItems').append(selected);
                    $('#DisplayItems').append('</br>');
                }
                else {
                    alert('already selected choose another one...');
                }
            });
        });
```

here, i used "jQuery.inArray()" method to check existence of the value in the array...
if value not exists in the array method returns -1....

Comment: Excellent I Really appreciate ur knowledge